# I can not remove the gaps around the image on mobiles when I apply the background-color, using img or background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing a bug of image gap. I have been searching several questions here and at Google, but without success. See the small screenshot and click it to resize the image in new tab, notice the black upper gap and white lower gap I can see on mobiles, but on computers, it is gap-free:

[image: image gap bug]

I also tried to use SVG, it also gave gap.

Small CSS, using `img`:

```
.ondas
{
  background-color: black;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.ondas img
{
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0
}
```

Or using `background`:

```
.ondas
{
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url("../imagens/ondas-alternativo.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  border: 0;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

And HTML, using `img`:

```
<div class="ondas">
    <img alt="ondas" src="assets/imagens/ondas-alternativo.png">
</div>
```

Or using `background`:

```
<div class="ondas"></div>
```

My classmate prepared, using `img`, but it can't hide a bit:

```
.ondas 
{
  margin-top: 1em;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  background: #000;
}

.ondas img 
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  display: block;
}
```

[image]

You can see three jsfiddles:

- [JSFiddle – Using `img`](https://jsfiddle.net/2ck0gyea/)
- [JSFiddle – Using `background`](https://jsfiddle.net/gusbemacbe/hzdweksj/)
- [JSFiddle – Using my classmate's snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/gusbemacbe/gpfbqu9L/)